# How do I return wrapped C++ Objects in Cython from another wrapped Object?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I've been wrapping C++ Classes with Cython. Now I have the following problem: Class A has a method foo() which returns an instance of Class B. Both are C++ classes. Both are wrapped in Cython to Class PyA and PyB. I want to make the method foo() accessible for users in a way, that the user calls PyA_object.foo() and gets a PyB_object. How do I implement the method?

```
cimport cppClassA

cdef class A:
    cdef cppClassA.A *ptr
    ...
def foo():
    return self.ptr.foo()
```

This way I return the direct C++ Class B, but I want to return a PyB. Therefore I need to create a PyB Object, but how do I construct the **cinit**() method of PyB? How can I give the returned object from self.ptr.foo() to a new PyB object and return it instead?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear from your question whether `foo` returns by pointer or value (i.e. whether it has the signature `B* foo()` or `B foo()`). What you have to do depends on this - I've shown both.

The problem that I think you're run into is that you the `__init__` or `__cinit__` method of `PyB` can only take Python objects as arguments, so you've got no way of passing the C++ `B` object in. The solution is to create a `PyB` that is either empty or has the default C++ object as `ptr` and then replace it.

The wrapping of the C++ code looks like this

```
cdef extern from "somefile.hpp":
    cdef cppclass A:
        B foo1()
        B* foo2()

    cdef cppclass B:
        # only need to provide these for foo1_alternative
        B()
        B(const B&)
```

Note that I've provided two versions of `foo` - `foo1` which returns by value and `foo2` which returns a pointer.

The Python `B` holder (`PyB`) looks like

```
cdef class PyB:
    cdef B* ptr

    def __cinit__(self,make_ptr=True):
        if make_ptr:
            self.ptr = new B()
        else:
            self.ptr = NULL

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.ptr
```

I've provided an optional `make_ptr` argument which you can set to `False` to avoid setting `self.ptr` to anything.

The Python `A` holder (`PyA`) is then

```
cdef class PyA:
    cdef A* ptr

    # code goes here

    def foo1(self):
        cdef PyB val = PyB()
        val.ptr[0] = self.ptr.foo1() # use move (or copy) assignment operator

    def foo1_alternative(self):
        cdef PyB val = PyB(make_ptr=False)
        val.ptr = new B(self.ptr.foo1()) # use move (or copy) constructor

    def foo2(self):
        cdef PyB val = PyB(make_ptr=False)
        val.ptr = self.ptr.foo2()
```

For `foo2`, which returns a pointer, you just create an empty `PyB` and assign the `Foo*` you get back to `self.ptr`. For `foo1` you have two options, one of which involves creating a `PyB` with something in then using move (or copy) assignment operator to copy the data across. The second option involves creating an empty `PyB` and then using `B`s move (or copy) constructor to create a `B*`.

You're better off using the move constructor rather than the copy constructor if you can, but you don't need to tell Cython about either (C++ will pick the right one automatically).